# [Television-Settings]

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's be honest, some of us play console or even PC games on our television. [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134102/what-is-game-mode-on-my-tv-and-why-should-i-enable-it-when-playing-games) brings forth a valid question regarding the proper settings for a TV. (Should I use Game Mode for Games?) While it's a single question I feel that it could be useful for a question such as "I have a Vizio 32 Inch 2013 Model, what setting is best for X Game?"

For those of us who immerse ourselves in games and since Halloween is coming up. (Come on we all like playing scary games on halloween, I'm playing Dead Space 1 only on halloween) This would be beneficial for those of us who want the best experience possible for a given game. Settings are variable from monitor to monitor and game to game, but my question still stands, should we create a [television-settings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-settings) tag?

[settings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings) is also apparently not a thing, are questions such as these just ultimately too off-topic?

Comment: What purpose would the tag serve that is currently going unfulfilled?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie After the responses given I looked through tags for settings, Which I found had a relation to configuration. Is the settings tag real or just a pipe dream as there are no questions tagged with settings?

Comment: It's probably a tag that used to get used and was emptied for not serving any useful purpose.

Comment: Welp, that settles that. I'll just leave it at technical issues then.

Comment: As a creator of the question I wish to close the question because the consensus has been given. No to television settings and questions like them should be flagged. Got what I wanted.

Comment: Closing is used for questions that don't belong. This is a valid discussion for meta, so it should stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything about a question needs to be classified in a tag. Tags are justified only when they serve a function, such as filtering or collecting together related information.

[television-settings] doesn't do that. We are likely to never get a second question that could be categorised by *only* that tag, since the one you link is about the only question that could be asked that's sufficient near our topic to survive voting. More specific (on topic) questions are going to be about some specific configuration of a specific game and a specific TV, and it's the game that will be getting tagging there.

As an analogy, consider all our [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) questions – most have plenty of information about the specific computer, but we don't add tags to categorise their computer. We usually don't even like to use general OS or platform tags.

Comment: A solution that results in an untagged question is not a solution.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I don't believe I'm advocating that. I may have missed something? I believe [[tag:hardware]] is our general-purpose tag for this sort of thing.

Comment: Then your answer is extremely unclear. Also, we have [tag:monitor]

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz My answer is an explanation of why [television-settings] wouldn't be an acceptable tag.

Answer (score 7):

We have [monitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor). I'm not sure why we need a seperate one for televisions, and I *certainly* think [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) is inappropriate here.

Comment: I didnt think about monitor...would make sense. Well now I feel REALLY stupid.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely not want a tag of this nature.  TV's aren't our specialty; gaming is.

This does nothing to play towards our core expertise.  I'm not a fan of that question, as I don't really think it's about gaming.  The last thing we need is MORE questions of that nature.

Comment: While I'm sure you could have worded "No * infinity." better, I do agree with this post.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely wasn't the best way to put it.

Comment: So then is the general consensus about any configuration questions just leave it to die without tags?

Comment: @ColeBusby For the most part, these questions aren't a good fit for us.  In an ideal world, we'd close and delete these questions.

Comment: @fbueckert Okay, Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the on-topicness of such questions aside and simply assuming they were, I'd still see no reason for this tag when asking how to make a certain game look best on a TV. I do not expect anyone would want to search specifically for all [television-setting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television-setting) questions, nor would we have an expert on all things TV setting related.

If such questions were to exist, I'd think tagging them with the game name as usual would be sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the [performance tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)?

However, the desire to have questions like "I have a Vizio 32 Inch 2013 Model, what setting is best for X Game?" is something I disagree with.  As fbueckert has mentioned, we are not TV experts.  We are not even monitor experts.  It also seems unlikely for this to be something that changes by the game.

The question does **relate** to gaming, so I think it is valid for Arqade, but I would not encourage more.

Comment: [tag:performace] is already a terrible tag